# CMake PUBLIC / INTERFACE problems while linking

Tags: c, makefile, cmake

i've got a problem with CMake and linking / compiling a part of the project im working on.

The folder structure of the target looks like this:

```
── sleeptimer
    ├── config
    │   └── sl_sleeptimer_config.h
    ├── inc
    │   └── sl_sleeptimer.h
    └── src
        ├── sl_sleeptimer.c
        ├── sl_sleeptimer_hal.h
        ├── sl_sleeptimer_hal_prortc.c
        ├── sl_sleeptimer_hal_rtc.c
        └── sl_sleeptimer_hal_rtcc.c
```

The CMake file which should add this looks like the following:

```
project(service)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
        sleeptimer/src/sl_sleeptimer.c)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
        sleeptimer/config
        sleeptimer/inc
        sleeptimer/src)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} common_platform emlib)
```

But i'm getting errors while linking it:

```
platform/service/libservice.a(sl_sleeptimer.c.obj): In function `sl_sleeptimer_init':
/mnt/c/Users/username/Downloads/_test/gecko_sdk/platform/service/sleeptimer/src/sl_sleeptimer.c:152: undefined reference to `sleeptimer_hal_init_timer'
/mnt/c/Users/username/Downloads/_test/gecko_sdk/platform/service/sleeptimer/src/sl_sleeptimer.c:153: undefined reference to `sleeptimer_hal_enable_int'
/mnt/c/Users/username/Downloads/_test/gecko_sdk/platform/service/sleeptimer/src/sl_sleeptimer.c:154: undefined reference to `sleeptimer_hal_get_timer_frequency'
platform/service/libservice.a(sl_sleeptimer.c.obj): In function `sl_sleeptimer_stop_timer':
/mnt/c/Users/username/Downloads/_test/gecko_sdk/platform/service/sleeptimer/src/sl_sleeptimer.c:313: undefined reference to `sleeptimer_hal_disable_int'
platform/service/libservice.a(sl_sleeptimer.c.obj): In function `sl_sleeptimer_get_tick_count':
/mnt/c/Users/username/Downloads/_test/gecko_sdk/platform/service/sleeptimer/src/sl_sleeptimer.c:428: undefined reference to `sleeptimer_hal_get_counter'
platform/service/libservice.a(sl_sleeptimer.c.obj): In function `set_comparator_for_next_timer':
/mnt/c/Users/username/Downloads/_test/gecko_sdk/platform/service/sleeptimer/src/sl_sleeptimer.c:1091: undefined reference to `sleeptimer_hal_enable_int'
/mnt/c/Users/username/Downloads/_test/gecko_sdk/platform/service/sleeptimer/src/sl_sleeptimer.c:1092: undefined reference to `sleeptimer_hal_set_compare'
platform/service/libservice.a(sl_sleeptimer.c.obj): In function `update_first_timer_delta':
/mnt/c/Users/username/Downloads/_test/gecko_sdk/platform/service/sleeptimer/src/sl_sleeptimer.c:1100: undefined reference to `sleeptimer_hal_get_counter'
```

All the undefined functions are declared within `sl_sleeptimer_hal.h`.

I'm kinda lost, since i more or less just started learning make / CMake.

Comment: You need to provide more info. Specifically, where are those undefined functions defined? Looks like you probably need to add all those `.c` files into `add_library`.

Comment: Adding `sleeptimer/src` into `target_include_directories` does not build all the C files in that directory. It just tells the compiler to look there for header files.

Comment: The undefined functions are defined within `sl_sleeptimer_hal.h`
I've added `sleeptimer/src` to `target_include_directories` because of `sl_sleeptimer_hal.h` @kaylum

Comment: Are you sure those functions are **defined** in the header file? That would be unusual. Header files generally only contain function prototypes and not the full function implementation/definition.

Comment: You were right about adding all the other files, my fault. And thanks for pointing that out. Also thos functions arent defined in the header, also my fault, just the prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are not adding all your source files.
I've also adding some suggestions. Default to PRIVATE unless you know you need PUBLIC/INTERFACE.

```
# Your project and your targets should never have the same name btw
project(SERVICE
 LANGUAGES C
)

add_library(service)

# Add all your source files
target_sources(service PRIVATE 
    sleeptimer/src/sl_sleeptimer.c
    sleeptimer/src/sl_sleeptimer_hal_prortc.c
    sleeptimer/src/sl_sleeptimer_hal_rtc.c
    sleeptimer/src/sl_sleeptimer_hal_rtcc.c
)

# EDIT:
# You probably want 1 or all of these to be PUBLIC depending on your circumstances.
target_include_directories(service 
# Clients don't need to know these include directories exist
PRIVATE
    sleeptimer/config
    sleeptimer/src

# Both service and clients that link against service need this include directory
PUBLIC
    sleeptimer/inc
)

target_link_libraries(service PRIVATE common_platform emlib)
```

EDIT:

Basic explanation on PRIVATE/INTERFACE/PUBLIC:

PRIVATE means only the target service sees it.
INTERFACE means only the target that links against service see it.
PUBLIC is a combination of PRIVATE/INTERFACE.

INTERFACE is generally only used for header only libraries, or very special cases.

To get a really good in depth explanation I'd recommend Professional CMake:
A Practical Guide (https://crascit.com/professional-cmake/)

Comment: I've thought I have to specify INTERFACE for header files which will be referenced by other targets?
You say my project and target shouldn't use the same name. Does this apply if this is just a "sub"-project or target of a bigger project?

Comment: Your project name and target name should always be different. This is because cmake variables depend on the project name, which could cause serious confusion.

Also you generally don't want header filers to be INTERFACE at all. INTERFACE is a very specific circumstance. However you most likely want inlude_directories to be public.

Comment: Some include_directories to be precise not all

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Could you still elaborate a bit further or give me a wink what i would have to read about the INTERFACE specifier. In my understanding those are files which are used by my target and also by other targets within the project?
Since I need this head to compile this target and im also using it within my own code this should be an INTERFACE.

Comment: I added a basic explanation on PRIVATE/INTERFACE/PUBLIC. You probably want your "inc" directory to be public.